# Laravel TokenMissmatch by multiple videos

Tags: jquery, html, laravel

I added a gallery to my application. If I add this

```
<input type="file" name="videos[]">
```

with jQuery and I insert more than one video, I get a TokenMissmatch Exception from Laravel.

But if I only add one video, everything work fine.

Does somebody know why?

Comment: Try to change the `post_max_size` in your php.ini, when your POST is too big, it just flushes everything that's why there's no token and the TokenMismatch Exception is thrown.

Comment: @PeterPan666
Thanks man, now it worked nice :-)

Comment: Glad to here it ;)